# Externalize service configuration in several angular apps that has the same configs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I have several AngularJS apps that they all have some common dependencies like `angular-translate`. All the angular apps have the same configuration (in `app.js`) for `angular-translate`.

I am looking for a way to externalize the configuration of `angular-translate` in all these apps. In a way that I will make the changes in one place (maybe a service?) and then the configs will be applied to the apps.

Btw, I am new to Angular world, your **precise** suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to make the App's pull the configuration file or you want to deliver the configuration files when a application build happened (push).

Comment: @lin I already shared the configuration files (such as languages and their translations). Now, I need to configure angular-translate in different apps to load those files from the shared location. These configuration is going to be repeated in all the angular apps, which I am trying to avoid

Answer (score 0):

You can create an angular module config function in a separate project that all of your projects in your projects import and use. Angular allows you to have as many module().config functions as you want. The same goes for .run functions.

Example

```
// Some common file available to all projects
angular.module('common-config', [
  'angular-translate'
  /* other common dependencies here */
]).config(['$translateProvider',
  function ($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');

    // Other configuration here.
  }]);

// App 1
angular.module('app-one', ['common-config']).run(/*...*/);

// App 2
angular.module('app-two', ['common-config']).run(/*...*/);

// App 3
angular.module('app-three', ['common-config']).run(/*...*/);
```